# Detecting navigation in FF add ons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am porting a Chrome extension to FF using 'FF Addon SDK'. In the background script (main.js) file, I need to use the FF equivalent of...

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener()
```

and

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()
```

I noticed that require("sdk/tabs").on only has open, close, finish, etc., but nothing to do with the navigation.

I see a few solutions that use Page-Mod or show the solution for the old XUL way of developing FF Extensions. I am specifically looking for an FF Addon SDK (only) solution.

Appreciate any inputs.

EDIT: I was able to figure out an alternative for chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener() by using Progress Listener. Apparently, in FF it is called onLocationChange. Still looking for an alternative to chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to figure it out. We need to use the onStateChange listener. To mimic onBeforeNavigation, we need to not only check for STATE_START, but also STATE_IS_DOCUMENT.

```
var progressListener = {
    QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIWebProgressListener, Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference]),

    onLocationChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aURI) {
        if (aRequest && aURI) {
            console.log('onLocationChange: ' + aURI.spec);
        }
    },

    onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
        var status = Ci.nsIWebProgressListener;

        if(aStateFlags&status.STATE_START && aStateFlags&status.STATE_IS_DOCUMENT) {
            console.log('onStateChange: ' + aRequest.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIChannel).originalURI.spec);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there isn't any suitable replacement for chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener().
Found myself in the same situation a week ago. Tried using nsIWebProgressListener.onStateChange for STATE_START. Didnot work as expected.
your best bet would be:
1.) use onLocationChange event, that'd give you the URI of the location that is being loaded.
2.) intercept Httprequest. Filter out one for top level and call it onbeginnavigate.

Let me know if you find other means.

Comment: I am using onLocationChange as well, but it seems to fire a lot slower than onBeforeNavigate in Chrome. Can you give more details or a sample code for intercepting HttpRequest.

Comment: refer to this documentation:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_the_tab_that_fires_the_http-on-modify-request_notification. There are no add-on sdk methods available. You need to port this example to use js-xpcom

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a `onBeforeUnload`/`onUnload` event from your framescript.