# Fire Fox Extension (Observers) - Trigger "http-on-modify-request" only once

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In reality, I am trying to capture the event immediately after a user presses ENTER on the address bar and moments before onLocationChange. I have an observer setup by using the following link as a guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads, and have something similar to the below.

However, the console print many URLs, even the images and scripts. How can I modify the code such that the function is triggered only once or gets disabled until the address bar changes or a link is clicked.

I guess I can set my own variable to track whether a request has been triggered on the URL, but want to know if there is a more efficient solution.

```
var httpRequestObserver = {
    ioService: Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService),

    observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
                if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {

                    var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);

                    console.log(httpChannel.URI.spec);
                }
            },

    register: function() {
        this.observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request", false);
    },

    unregister: function() {
        this.observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request");
    }
};

httpRequestObserver.register();
```

Comment: Use the observer service is not safe, it will likely catch a request from somewhere else, it is very possible there can be tons of requests firing in todays ajax loving world. I think nsIWebProgressListener would be better, but that also is vulnerable to the same thing. I'm not sure what the best solution would be its a good question something I'm interested in as well. But if you do this or hte nsIWebProgressListener, you just `unregister` on the first trigger. Here is how to attach nsiWebProgress: https://github.com/Noitidart/Full-Stop/blob/master/resources/scripts/framescript.js

Comment: In reality this question is somewhat related to my original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152592/detecting-navigation-in-ff-add-ons. I need to get the URL the moment a user types and presses enter. Sometimes URLs such as google.com get redirected to https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=_lIrVvHwL6bv8wfH2JHIAw&gws_rd=ssl,cr&fg=1 or something. I need the original one before the navigation begun. I am already using a progressListner, need something quicker. Kango has a BEFORE_NAVIGATE event. Not sure how they do it. Trying to reverse their code.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question, but I used observers to mimic Chrome Extensions' WebRequest and onBeforeSendHeaders listener. The earlier examples I saw used observers, but now I can just use WebRequest.jsm. I don't need an answer to this question anymore, but leaving it open, since it is intriguing and may guide future people in here.

Comment: Add the observer, and in the `observer:` part put in `httpRequestObserver.unregister()` that catches one and stops.

Comment: @Noitidart Once unregistered, will the observer trigger when the user changes the URL  by clicking on a link or typing in a new address? If it does, then it may not be practical always. In addition, requests come from various sources - scripts, webservices, the actual website link the user clicked, images, etc. It's unlikely, I'd always get the link that the user clicked (which is what I want) in the first observation.

Comment: Nope, when unregisterd it will not trigger ever again. Yes thats why I recommend against this method. There has to be a more reliable method. nsIWebProgressListener can do it I'm sure but its tricky, there are so many flags to mess with.

Comment: NP, thanks for your inputs. I did eventually use an alternative solution (comment #3). Not sure what to choose as the answer here, or do I just let it be open?

Comment: Post up as solution what you used then we can see that and get you better. I honestly would attach a page unload event, and that even holds where its going to next I'm pretty sure in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally used "http-on-modify-request" observer, since it was the suggested place to modify the referer in the request header. However, I realised later that Chrome's Web Request APIs were available and used the following code instead.

```
const {WebRequest} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/WebRequest.jsm", {});

WebRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(setReferrer, { types: ['main_frame'] }, ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']);

function setReferrer(e) {
    //some other code

    for (var i in e.requestHeaders) {
        if (e.requestHeaders[i].name === 'Referer') {
            e.requestHeaders.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    e.requestHeaders.push({name : 'Referer', value : 'myreferer.com'});
    return { requestHeaders: e.requestHeaders };
}
```